# How to get root cause for broken topology in ActiveMQ Artemis HA cluster and how to fix

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have setup a simple HA cluster with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14.0. This cluster consists of a live and of a backup broker. Network stuff is configured statically in `broker.xml`. The plan is that backup becomes active and takes over if the live broker fails. Furthermore backup shall go back to replication mode if live becomes active again.

This has worked for some months without any issue, but I had to restart the live broker due to a failure while updating the security to force re-creating configuration. Touching `broker.xml` did read the configuration, but security settings remained broken, so I did restart which fixed that issue.

Backup broker became active, but still remained active after live broker was available again. I did also a restart on backup broker to get rid of dual head. Problem started here. Artemis log file of backup broker after restart had last line:

```
2021-09-22 15:49:02,269 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221109: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Backup Server version 2.14.0 [null] started, waiting live to fail before it gets active
```

Log lines for `AMQ221024` (synchronized with live-server) and `AMQ221031` (backup announced) are missing. I guess replication was not started. Re-starting backup broker had same result.

Since that time it's also impossible to connect to live broker using Core protocol. Error message from core client is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at com.havi.artemis.client.QueueExample.main(QueueExample.java:24)
Caused by: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:743)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
    ... 2 more
```

I did some debugging and tracing core client session and found out core client is waiting for receiving topology from broker, which never comes. On working core connections I find something like this in trace output regarding a "ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3":

```
13:54:49,174 TRACE [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl] RemotingConnectionID=fb1c17b5 handling packet PACKET(ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3)[type=122, channelID=0, responseAsync=false, requiresResponse=false, correlationID=-1, packetObject=ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3, exit=false, last=true, nodeID=c429f2bf-fe64-11eb-b36a-000d3a484732, pair=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=primary-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61000&host=aweltamq01-XXX, b=null], backupGroupName=null, uniqueEventID=1645919843047, scaleDownGroupName=null]
```

This output regarding the `ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3` is missing in the trace from the failed core connection to concerned live broker.

Inspecting topology of concerned live broker using HTTP Management Console gives:

```
topology on Topology@416d2970[owner=ClusterConnectionImpl@940774680[nodeUUID=5e6e8916-831b-11eb-b127-000d3abf018b, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=live-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=63001&host=awelpamq01-XXX, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=5e6e8916-831b-11eb-b127-000d3abf018b]]:
    nodes=0 members=0   Empty
```

Topology from a broker without issue for comparing how a topology should look like:

```
topology on Topology@4129cb4f[owner=ClusterConnectionImpl@429058804[nodeUUID=c429f2bf-fe64-11eb-b36a-000d3a484732, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=primary-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61000&host=aweltamq01-XXX, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=c429f2bf-fe64-11eb-b36a-000d3a484732]]:
    c429f2bf-fe64-11eb-b36a-000d3a484732 =&gt; TopologyMember[id = c429f2bf-fe64-11eb-b36a-000d3a484732, connector=Pair[a=TransportConfiguration(name=primary-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61000&host=aweltamq01-XXX, b=TransportConfiguration(name=backup-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61000&host=AWELPSONIC01-XXX], backupGroupName=null, scaleDownGroupName=null]
    nodes=2 members=1
```

I believe concerned live brokers topology should inherit also 2 nodes (live and backup), at least itself as node if backup broker is not available. I believe this topology with `nodes=0` is related to core client failing getting the topology. Furthermore I suspect backup broker fails to start replication because it opens a core connection first and waits forever for that topology.

How to get I this fixed without restarting the concerned life broker? I strongly believe if shutting down life broker there will be no clean fail-over due to replication not started. This will end up in another dual head situation, but this time with different messages in different queues. So, a restart would be needed to very well organized to stop all message senders first.

For reference this is the setup for life broker regarding cluster and HA:

```xml
      <connectors>
        <connector name="live-connector">tcp://awelpamq01.XXX:63001</connector>
        <connector name="backup-connector">tcp://awelpamq02.XXX:63001</connector>
      </connectors>

      <ha-policy>
        <replication>
          <master>
            <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
          </master>
        </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <cluster-user>prod-cluster-user</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>very_secret</cluster-password>

      <cluster-connections>
        <cluster-connection name="prod-cluster">
          <connector-ref>live-connector</connector-ref>
          <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
          <max-hops>0</max-hops>
          <static-connectors allow-direct-connections-only="true">
            <connector-ref>backup-connector</connector-ref>
          </static-connectors>
        </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

Backup Broker:

```xml
      <connectors>
        <connector name="live-connector">tcp://awelpamq01.XXX:63001</connector>
        <connector name="backup-connector">tcp://awelpamq02.XXX:63001</connector>
      </connectors>

      <ha-policy>
        <replication>
          <slave>
            <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
          </slave>
        </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <cluster-user>prod-cluster-user</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>also_very_secret_and_granted_same_as_live</cluster-password>

      <cluster-connections>
        <cluster-connection name="prod-cluster">
          <connector-ref>backup-connector</connector-ref>
          <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
          <max-hops>0</max-hops>
          <static-connectors allow-direct-connections-only="true">
            <connector-ref>live-connector</connector-ref>
          </static-connectors>
        </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

Comment: You've got too many questions here. You need to focus your question down to a single issue or your question is liable to be closed. Thanks!

Comment: I have set question focus on how to fix this and removed questions regarding technical background. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using shared-store or replication? Based on your description it sounds like you're using replication, but you never say explicitly so I want to clarify.

Comment: I'm using replication. Forgot to add the ha-policy in broker.xml snippets, but I have included that missing part now.

Comment: For what it's worth, using replication with a single live/backup pair is very dangerous as it's vulnerable to [split-brain](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/network-isolation.html) (which you appear to be calling "dual head"). I recommend you use shared storage or if you must use replication then I strongly recommend you move to the latest release and configure the new [pluggable quorum voting](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#pluggable-quorum-vote-replication-configurations) with ZooKeeper.

Comment: Our Artemis Broker is located in Azure and I lack the knowledge to create a solid setup with shared storage there. I agree to moving to latest release and setting up solid quorum voting.

Answer (score 0):

Found how to fix in version ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14.0 without removing data directory and losing all messages:

1. Shutdown backup broker, it's dual head anyway.
2. Remove or comment out <cluster-connections> in primary brokers broker.xml
3. Restart primary broker.
4. Restore <cluster-connections> part in primary brokers broker.xml
5. Restart primary broker.
6. Start backup broker.

This seems to force primary broker to clear and restore something in data directory what ever it is. Topology on primary broker shows "nodes=2" and last log line of backup broker is "AMQ221031: backup announced" now.